# Disable inverse foreign keys creation during tables export via querydsl maven plugin

Tags: java, maven, querydsl

I'm looking for a way to disable inverse foreign keys creation. Currently querydsl maven plugin automatically creates InvForeignKey-entries during a build-process. 
For instance,

1. Table CUSTOMER has pk=customerId
2. Table PROVIDER has pk=providerId and fk=customerId
3. Table ABRACADABRA has pk=abraId and fk=customerId

Here is the plugin settings from pom:

```
   <plugin>
        <groupId>com.mysema.querydsl</groupId>
        <artifactId>querydsl-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <executions>
            <execution>
                <phase>generate-sources</phase>
                <goals>
                    <goal>export</goal>
                </goals>
            </execution>
        </executions>
        <configuration>
            <jdbcDriver>oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver</jdbcDriver>
            <jdbcUrl>${url}</jdbcUrl>
            <jdbcUser>${username}</jdbcUser>
            <jdbcPassword>${password}</jdbcPassword>
            <schemaPattern>${schema}</schemaPattern>
            <packageName>com.test.querydsl</packageName>
            <targetFolder>${project.basedir}/target/generated-sources/java</targetFolder>
            <tableTypesToExport>TABLE</tableTypesToExport>
            <tableNamePattern>
                CUSTOMER, PROVIDER
            </tableNamePattern>
        </configuration>
    </plugin>
```

In my situation, I want to generate types only for tables CUSTOMER(QCustomer) and PROVIDER(QProvider) and do not keep any information about ABRACADABRA. However, querydsl-plugin force me to add the undesired table into tableNamePattern due to it generates something like that right into QCustomer!

```
public final com.mysema.query.sql.ForeignKey<QAbracadabra> _fkabracadabra = createInvForeignKey(Arrays.asList(customerId), Arrays.asList("CUSTOMERID"));
```

Is it possible not switch it off somehow? I still want generate normal foreign keys.